# Javascript not working when changing div location in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, move

I have used this method to make a slider popping up when clicking on a button:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

I have made my own button for it + some other changes. However — i have struggled for 2 days now, trying to figure out how to be able to move my button out of the div it was in the original script.

Because; when i move it out of the original div, tat looks like this:

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
```

It simply stops working.

At first i thought it had something to do with the fact that the ID that started the slider animation, was defined as '(this')
So i ran a 'test' to figure out the ID that 'this' was and replaced it with that. 
But still; nothing happens when i move it into another div.

I can move it out of all divs just below the 'body' tag — and there it will work as well.

Here is the html-part

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
    <a href="#" onclick="hotelmenu()" id="hotels"><img src="xxx.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("hotelmenu")
      $('#hotels').click(function() {
           /*alert(this.id);*/
         $('#hotels').next().slideToggle();
      });
  });
 </script>
```

I am a rookie when it comes to javascript, so please forgive me if this is dumb question.

Just to sum up; i just want to be able to move my button somewhere else than this one particular div.

Comment: Could it be that `$("#hotels).next()` tries to look for the next hotel element? Maybe you should do `$("#hotels").children()`, since I assume you are trying to slide the next image... It's because next() used to work because the element _next_ to the button was the element you wanted to slide. Now it isn't, now you want to slide the element thats a _child_ of your 'button' (actually, link).

Comment: document.getElementById("hotelmenu") doesn't do much as you don't assign this to a variable and your click function is for an element with ID="hotels". Can you show where that is in your mark-up in relation to the div you wish to slide. You could just try using $('#slidebottom').slideToggle();

Comment: The issue is probably related to the fact that you are using `next()`, once you move the div, the next element is not going to be the one you thought it was.

Comment: Also, you are calling a function that does not exists on your 'onclick' event. Try wrapping the whole `$("#hotel").....` into a function like `function hotelmenu(){ ... stuff here .... }`

Comment: In your example there is nothing to toggle. Can you post the entire html?

Comment: Hi and thank you for answering. 

I am not allowed to paste so much text in here, so i will send you a link to a place i have uploaded the entire HTML. Hopefully you can grab the source code from that.

http://cphz4media2.com/brokop/HTML_03/em_front_v2.html

Comment: Hi again

Thank you for all your help. You guided me in the right direction. It turns out i had to go for the 'inner' DIV. 

Thank you so much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I get it in total, so...

Your slider is based on next(), which means: starting at $("#hotels"), the function is binding the sliding functionality to the element directly after $("#hotels") - literally the next element, and ONLY the next element.

If the element you want to toggle is moved to another position in your HTML, the function will stop working, because it strictly refers to a position in the HTML, not to a designated element (like it would be done by a query selector).

Maybe you could post your whole HTML?

Answer (score 0):

And thank you for answering.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <!--*********** Aktivere CSS3 selectors i IE 7 & 8 ***********

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.2/html5shiv.js"></script>

        <script src="//s3.amazonaws.com/nwapi/nwmatcher/nwmatcher-1.2.5-min.js"></script>
        <script src="//html5base.googlecode.com/svn-history/r38/trunk/js/selectivizr-1.0.3b.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title></title>

    <!--*********** CSS ***********-->
    <link href="../../css/dev_brokop_em.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <!--
    <link href="../../css/mediumstyles.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="../../css/smallstyles.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 610px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    -->
    <link href="../../css/jquery.fullPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!--*********** JS ***********-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>


    <!--*********** Aktivere Media Queries i IE 7 & 8 ***********-->
    <script src="../../js/respond.min.js"></script> 

    </head>

    <body id="em">

    <div id="fullpage">

        <div class="section" id="bg">


    <!--************ Bottom Logos ************-->


                <div id="circlesbottom">
                <img src="../../img/experience_meetings/em_circles.png" border="0">
                </div>


                <div id="logobottom">
                <img src="../../img/experience_meetings/em_logo.jpg" border="0" width="100" height="100">
                </div>

                        <a href="javascript:changeImage()" onclick="hotelmenu()" id="hotels"><img id="pic" class="portrait" src="../../img/experience_meetings/hotels_off.png" border="0" width="100" height="100"></a>   


                <div id="content">  

                <div id="movie_button">
                <img src="../../img/experience_meetings/em_button_movie.png" width="90" height="90" border="0">
                </div>
                    <div id="content_inside">
                    <h1>EXPERIENCE MEETINGS</h1><br>
                    <h2>Daectisquia volum velent audam dit qui adipiet pra posaepe liaspidebite veliqui vendit plia nus con nectur?Aqui berum que ommolenis quiasperum eturepe sunt alit exped quassunt prestem quam aut reiunt quae volupitatet omnient ma exerisq uundam fuga. Nem. Itatecatur, officiu reicietur?</h2>
                    </div>


                </div>




    <!--************* Slidebottom ************-->
            <div id="slidebottom" class="slide">




                <div id="inner">

                    <div id="bottomslider_wrapper">

                        <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                        <h1>DANMARK</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                        <h1>SVERIGE</h1>
                        </div>

                        <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                        <h1>NORGE</h1>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--************** Turn Hotel button on and off ************-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var newsrc = "hotels_on.jpg";

    function changeImage() {
      if ( newsrc == "hotels_on.jpg" ) {
        document.images["pic"].src = "../../img/experience_meetings/hotels_on.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "hotels_on";
        newsrc  = "hotels_off.jpg";
      }
      else {
        document.images["pic"].src = "../../img/experience_meetings/hotels_off.png";
        document.images["pic"].alt = "hotels_off";
        newsrc  = "hotels_on.jpg";
      }
    }
    </script>


    <!--************* Bottom slider ****************** -->
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          document.getElementById("hotelmenu")
          $('#hotels').click(function() {
              /*alert(this.id);*/
            $('#hotels').next().slideToggle();
          });
        });
    </script>


    <!--*********** fullpage.js ***********-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out with the help of your logic. Here is the code i ended up with.
Thank you all for great help! :)

```
<div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
            <div id="inner">   
                <div id="bottomslider_wrapper">

                    <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                    <h1>DANMARK</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                    <h1>SVERIGE</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="bottomslider_content_01">
                    <h1>NORGE</h1>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.getElementById("hotelmenu")
      $('#hotels').click(function() {
          /*alert(this.id);*/
        $('#inner').slideToggle();
      });
    });
</script>
```